# Pure inductor with no resistive battery

Tags: inductance

In case of pure inductor with dc source E= Ldi/dt . Is it mean that all work done by battery is stored in form of magnetic field energy?

Comment: di/dt is zero for a dc source

Comment: @BobD If you connect a perfect current source to a perfect inductor, then the current will rise linearly in time and that rise will never stop. If there is a current limiting resistor in there, then the initial rise will be linear and the current will eventually level off (exponentially). The answer to the question is positive. Yes, all the energy will be stored in the magnetic field. For a finite current that energy is E=LI^2/2.

Comment: @FlatterMann  I was referring to steady state not  transient (switching) conditions

Comment: @FlatterMann slight correction: the current rises linearly when a constant *voltage* source is connected to an inductor d(kt)/dt = k

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inductor back emf](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/676543/inductor-back-emf)

Comment: This is an odd circuit you've posed (assuming I'm reading it correctly). Ordinarily the DC voltage source (battery) voltage is, in some approximation *independent* of the load and constant. But here, you've specified that the voltage E is proportional to the time rate of change of the inductor current (here I assume you have just the DC voltage source and pure inductor connected together). Is that what you meant?

Comment: @hyportnex Good point. Never blog when you are tired. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The way I understood it is that the question was about the current ramp on an inductor with constant voltage. That's a very common application in DC-DC conversion. A switching element (MOSFET or bipolar transistor) connects the input voltage source to the inductor until the current reaches a certain level. Then the switch is turned off. The energy stored in the inductor can now be transferred to the secondary side of the circuit with a second switch (often just a diode). But maybe that's just a projection of mine because I had to deal with these power supplies a lot.